# magento is extremely slow, more than a minute

Tags: php, magento, profiler, mage

I saw the profiler results, observed that a lot of entries are taking up more than 50 seconds.
here is my profiler result
http://14.140.202.163/profiler.html

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Wait until you get to importing products. Magento is as slow as hard shit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to stem from `frontend\ultimo\default\template\catalin_seo/catalog/product/list.phtml`.

It's tough to say exactly why because the profiler doesn't often give a perfect view, but my guess would be that the calls to `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable::getUsedProducts()` are a big part of the problem.  I am guessing that somewhere in your category page you are iterating over the products and calling `getUsedProducts()` for each.  I say that because that method is called over 9,000 times.

That said, (again, I am guessing a little bit here), the problem itself does not seem to be directly in the `getUsedProducts()` call, but rather in the `_afterLoad()` collection hook.  If you look at the profiler code in that method it looks like TTT4 is the worst offender which is making calls to `$this->_loadPrices();`. 9,000 calls to `getUsedProducts()` implies a lot of iteration but the `_afterLoad()` method is only called 31 times which means that the results of `getUsedProducts()` is being cached, i.e. not being reloaded.  So it would appear that something (though I can't say exactly what) is happening in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection::_loadPrices()`.